# Can I easily export users passwords from one app to another using authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Passwords are one-way encrypted and will remain so, but is there a way I can easily export these crypted passwords and use in a different app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about moving them from one database to another? Or allowing a different application access to the same database?

Either way, sure, that's fine as long as the logic in the new app uses exactly the same hashing/encryption algorithm to check the users' entered password with the stored one.